# Bitmap returned, Uri needed

Tags: android, android-intent

be kind this is my first post.

I have a Crop intent retuning and assigning the Bitmap to an ImageView. But what i want is the URI of the new bitmap.

How can i either get the Uri from the 'photo' var, or return the URI with the intent result.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)       

    case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:
        Log.d(TAG, "Returned from Crop");
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

        Uri uriCropped = data.getData();

        if (extras != null) {               
            Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
            Log.d(TAG, "Setting Crop preview with URI: " + uriCropped);
            ImageView mImageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImageView);
            mImageView2.setImageURI(uriCropped);


        }

        File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());            
        if (f.exists()) f.delete();

        startX(<URI of 'photo' needed>);
        break;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `photo` var only exists in memory and therefore it doesn't have a Uri. In case you need the Uri save it to the device storage and retrieve it with [Uri.fromFile(File file)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#fromFile%28java.io.File%29).

Comment: Xavi, thanks very much for your help and quick response. Worked a treat.